# Changing style of first column of panelGrid

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2

I have a `<h:panelGrid>` with two columns, and I want to left align the first column and right align the second column.  I have tried giving all the elements in the first column a class and then left aligning all of them.  However, my elements are outputText elements, and this doesn't work (I'm assigning the class to the span inside the table and not the `<td>`).  How do I assign a class to the actual `<td>` element of the first column of the panelGrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `columnClasses`attribute.

```
<h:panelGrid columnClasses="column1Class,column2Class">
    ...
</h:panelGrid>
```

Read more [here](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_panelGrid.html).